# How to continuously watch a directory for the presence of files with a certain file-extension?

Tags: php, while-loop, filesystems, infinite-loop, glob

For example, I want to continuously monitor a directory for the presence of `.xml` files.

As soon as a `.xml` file is found in that directory, the program should start processing on the file, e.g. reading the data inside the file, extracting useful data and further actions.

***Solution I tried to use:***

I tried to use an *INFINITE while loop* to *continuously* monitor the directory, and used `glob()` to check for the presence of files with `.xml` extension. `glob()` returns an array with paths of all files found.

So then within the infinite while loop, I check if the array returned by `glob()` is NON-EMPTY. If yes, then I read the file at each path in the array returned by `glob()` and do appropriate processing on the file.

The problem is that when i run it, I get

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Alpha\index.php on line 9
```

I believe this is due to the infinite while loop.

***Questions:***

1. Is my way of solving my problem a good way?
2. What should I do to bypass the above error?

Comment: You could use javascript `Server Sent Events` clientside and an infinite loop within a PHP script server side. The js client connects to the PHP script and receives any `Event-Stream` messages output by PHP. This would only run when you initiate the connection from the client whereas a cron job would run independently

Answer (score 2):

As an example of using SSE to achieve your stated intention of monitoring a directory

The PHP script that does the directory scans - in this example it is a simple `glob` but could be much more sophisticated using `recursiveIterator` etc

```
<?php
    /*
        sse.php
    */
    set_time_limit( 0 );
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', 1);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
    ob_end_clean();

    /* -- set headers -- */
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); /* !important! */
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
    header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Events');  

    /* -- utility function to send formatted sse message -- */
    if( !function_exists('sse_message') ){
        function sse_message( $evtname='dirmon', $data=null, $retry=1000 ){
            if( !is_null( $data ) ){
                echo "event:".$evtname."\r\n";
                echo "retry:".$retry."\r\n";
                echo "data:" . json_encode( $data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS );
                echo "\r\n\r\n";
            }
        }
    }

    /* How often messages will be pushed to the client app */
    $sleep = 5;

    /* The directory to monitor */
    $dir = 'c:/temp/';

    /* The name of the event to monitor in js client app */
    $evt = 'dirmon';


    while( true ){
        if( connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL or connection_aborted() ) {
            break;
        }

        /* Methods here to scan directory and produce data to send */
        $files=glob( $dir . '*.xml' );
        $count = count( $files );

        $payload=array(
            'dir'   =>  $dir,
            'files' =>  $count
        );

        /* -- prepare and send sse message -- */
        sse_message( $evt, $payload );

        /* -- Send output -- */
        if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
        @flush();

        /* wait */
        sleep( $sleep );
    }

    if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) {
        for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
        @ob_end_clean();
    }
?>
```

The client page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SSE</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var count=0;
            function bindEvtSource(){

                var evt='dirmon';
                var url='/sse.php';

                if ( !!window.EventSource ) {

                    var evtSource = new EventSource( url );

                    evtSource.addEventListener( 'open', function(e){
                        console.log(e.type);
                    },false);

                    evtSource.addEventListener( 'error', function(e){
                        console.error('%o %s',e,e.type);
                    },false);

                    evtSource.addEventListener( evt, function(e){
                        var json=JSON.parse(e.data);
                        var files=json.files;
                        if( files!=count ) {
                            count=files;
                            alert('contents changed - process changes! Send Ajax Request? etc etc');
                        }
                        document.getElementById('dirdata').innerHTML=e.data;
                    },false);



                } else {
                    alert('Server Sent Events are not supported in this browser');
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvtSource, false );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='dirdata'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could use the response to then perform further actions by initiating a function within js - ie: send Ajax Request to a script that will do whatever processing you require ( Server Sent Events are uni-directional and you can send / receive - only receive! )

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer. Right now I am learning about CRON jobs, because I had started with it before I saw your answer. Since I am a newbie, it is taking some time. Once I am done, I will try your answer and read about Server End Scripts. Then I will accept your answer. Upvoting it right now